# Entity Framework Checklist to improve the performance

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am developing  a project using Entity Framework 4. Having around 50 Entities, mostly all the tables are having relation with user table. The searching a user is bit more time to return the results. In user table I have removed navigation properties even it is taking more time.
Mostly on web the performance guidelines are provided for any particular scenario/problem. Is there any common checklist available for improving performance of Entity Frame work?

Search the user as dynamically like follows

```
 var searchPredication = (from user in entities.Users
 where ((searchKeyword == "") || (searchField != "" && searchKeyword != "" &&
 searchField == "BarCode" && user.BarCode == searchKeyword)||
(searchField == "LastName" && user.LastName == searchKeyword)  ||
(searchField == "FirstName" && user.FirstName == searchKeyword))) && !user.IsDeleted 
select user).FirstOrDefault();
```

And also I need to give some more information about common performance management in EF.

Comment: What is the real problem here? Is the query slow or is it just a problem because you must execute the query?

Comment: I have updated the problem in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really any 'Checklist' but here's some tips for making sure your sites perform well:

- Always keep a large volume of data in your dev database, if you inject millions of dummy rows, it will exaggerate performance problems while you are still in development.
- Use performance tests, if we have a high volume site we setup at least a test per page to sanity check load times. This allows you to pick out outlying pages.
- Avoid really complex LINQ statements, they are normally (but not always) wrong, mostly you can achieve things simply.
- Enumerate your set as soon as you have the correct data. This avoids accidently complicating the query in your display code. (ie use ToList or ToArray)
- Use EFProfiler or SQLProfiler on complicated queries to validate that the SQL seems reasonable.

Hope this helps, overall peformance is more of an art than a science. Its a bit of a sliding scale.